# Why Does Ubuntu Keep Shutting Down When I Type Quickly?

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, asus

I'm on an ASUS ROG machine running Ubuntu 20.04. The system will try to shut down whenever I type quickly. Nothing else seems to trigger it (I'm pretty sure it's not overheating, and it doesn't shut down on its own).

I am not experiencing the same issues with a dual-boot of Windows 10 on the same laptop (but different disk drive). It doesn't seem to be a hardware issue.

I've searched on this site and on other forums, but haven't seen anyone that had a similar issue caused just by typing quickly. Others had the same issue caused by heat, yes, but mine seems to be unique.

(Edited to mention that I do not face this issue on Windows 10)

Comment: Actually it's so unique. It happens on Windows 10? I have another Asus laptop.

Comment: @Noctis, it happens on ubuntu, not Windows 10 :) Mine is a gaming laptop.

Comment: @user535733 I just tried it, and was unable to reproduce it on the 'Try Ubuntu' environment on my Ubuntu LiveUSB, no matter how quickly I typed. What does this indicate? :)

Comment: It indicates that you seem to NOT have a hardware problem. You already knew that since it doesn't happen on Windows 10, but we lacked that data when I asked.

Comment: @user535733 My apologies, I forgot to include that. Are there any fixes for my issue on Ubuntu? Anything I'm missing out?

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Asus ROG strix G713QR with Ubuntu 21.04. Did not have it with Windows or Live USB either

Comment: Fascinating. Apparently for years there have been problems with gnome gamers: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/825

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem on Asus ROG strix G713QR with Ubuntu 21.04. Did not have it with Windows or Live USB either. Following worked for me:

`Settings -> Power -> Suspend & Power Button -> Power Button Behavior -> [Nothing]`

*Worth to note: You can partially eliminate the problem with the solution above, but the root of the problem will still be there. I have discovered that my system somehow triggers the power button behaviour when I type quickly. And it actually still does it! It just does not try to shutdown anymore, but it does go off focus from the writing app as if I have pressed the shutdown button. And it does try to shutdown when I type fast, right after I switch the power button behaviour back to the original. Totally weird.*

Comment: Old problem it appears: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/825 You could try writing a script hooked up to power/shutdown button. The script wouldn't steal window focus but just log the event to a file.

Comment: Sounds good. But I need to add that this does not only appear at gnome shell but it also happens at firefox url bar for example. Or anywhere that I can type anything. And it does not happen when I press other keys such as ctrl, alt, tab, shift at the other hand.

Comment: Firefox and all other applicadtions use gnome shell: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell I think maybe you are talking about gnome-terminal and not gnome shell?

Comment: True. That was my ignorance right there :d Thank you, now I know what Gnome shell means :) Btw, the first link said that the real reason was this anti ghosting tech that gamer keyboards have so I have switched to my ordinary keyboard and voila! Problem solved! [_using a common keyboard the gnome does not hang, but by using a gamer mouse with numerical keys the gnome hangs like the gamer keyboard._](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/825#note_407162)

Comment: Sounds great. I don't have gamer keybaord, except built into my laptop whos keyboard I never use (Logitech wireless keyboard and mouse instead, never touch laptop keyboard or trackpad). I imagine the gaming problem with gnome shell is related to dbus becoming overwhelmed. I bought gaming laptop for speed not for games.

Comment: exactly my intent and my keyboard and my mouse :)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with my Asus Rog strix g15 with Ryzen 5900HX and 3070. The problem is with the keyboard drivers for linux. Actually they require some extra filtering for the events emitted from the keyup and keydown.
There is this project https://asus-linux.org/ dedicated towards solving various problems faced in the asus laptop hardware and for controlling backlit, fan etc in the asus hardware.

Keyboard related patches are being merged to linux kernel and will be avaiable from 5.13.x series of linux kernel which will be available from end of june or start of july based on the RC performance.
see this blog https://asus-linux.org/blog/updates-2021-05-06/